# How to set a value with props?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the initial value from prop, but sometimes prop does not have data Is this the correct way to pass the props ?

```
const [brokerId,setBrokerId]=useState(props.data ?props.data.BrokerId :null)
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Seems fine to me

Comment: this works! you can also use nullish coalescing and optional chaining:

`props.data?.BrokerId ?? null`